# How can I set altitudeMode in KML encoding with GeoTools?

Tags: java, kml, google-earth, geotools

I am exporting a set of points to KML using the GeoTools KML encoder.

It works fine, but my points are expressed as lat, lon, alt, and they are exported as such, but Google Earth presents them clamped to the surface.

I read [here](http://dagik.org/kml_intro/E/point.html) that I need to set the `altitudeMode` attribute. How would I do that with the GeoTools encoder?

Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Converts the given point array to KML.
 * @param points The array of points to be converted.
 * @param os The target output stream where the resulting KML is to be
 * written. This method does not close the stream.
 */
public static void toKml(Point[] points, OutputStream os) {
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder sftb = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    sftb.setName("points");
    sftb.add("geomtery", Point.class, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84_3D);
    SimpleFeatureType type = sftb.buildFeatureType();

    DefaultFeatureCollection features = new DefaultFeatureCollection();

    SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        builder.add(points[i]);
        features.add(builder.buildFeature(Integer.toString(i)));
    }

    Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
    encoder.setIndenting(true);
    try {
        encoder.encode(features, KML.kml, os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("While converting " +
                Arrays.toString(points) + " to KML.", e);
    }
}
```